# Xamarin iOS project getting timeout errors on httpwebrequest, same code works fine in Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a cross platform Xamarin app. On one of my pages I'm calling an external API in an async method. It works great when I run it in Android but once I try to run it in the iOS simulator it throws a `System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out` exception. Stepping through the code, the error is caused by the line `var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();` in the snippet below.

```
var url = "https://url-to-api";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

string result;

request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

request.Timeout = 20000;

var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

As I said above, this works perfectly in the Android project, and I can hit the API and get data back just fine using Postman. Can anyone shed some light on why this seems to only be happening in the iOS simulator?

Comment: try it using Safari on the device/simulator - it could be a basic connectivity issue

Comment: Hi , have a look at this document about service connected in Mac/iOS . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/http-stack And check that whether be helpful .

Comment: @Jason I checked Safari on the simulator, no connection. So I checked Safari on the Mac, no connection. Every other device on the network could connect to the internet. The Mac just decided not to for some reason while still remaining available on the network to compile the app. Put that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it using Safari on the device/simulator - it could be a basic connectivity issue

Comment: I talked to one of my co-workers about this issue. Apparently this bug has been happening since they upgraded to Catalina. Internet connection will just randomly drop and give no indication. A reboot fixes it until it crops up again.